# How do I create a specific date in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, date

I need to execute a `INSERT` statement writing a date with a `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Would `to_date('2021-09-28','YYYY-MM-DD')` work?

Comment: `date` values do **not** have "a format". So it's completely irrelevant if you use `to_date('2021-09-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` or `to_date('28.09.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`

Answer (score 2):

`YYYY-MM-DD` is the the [ISO 8601 standard date format and unambiguous default in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE). Just insert your date literally.

The [type `date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) is stored as a 4-byte integer quantity internally, which does not preserve any format. You can format any way you like on output with some basic locale settings or settings of your client, or explicitly with [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE).

Input with `to_date('2021-09-28','YYYY-MM-DD')` works, too. But you don't need [to_date()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) while operating with ISO format.