# Get start and end date time based on sequence of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table below with sample data.

| Date&Time | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:09 | Normal |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:10 | Normal |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:11 | Normal |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:12 | Warning |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:13 | Warning |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:14 | Warning |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:15 | Warning |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:16 | Error |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:17 | Error |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:18 | Warning |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:19 | Warning |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:20 | Warning |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:21 | Normal |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:22 | Normal |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:23 | Normal |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:24 | Warning |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:25 | Warning |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:26 | Warning |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:27 | Error |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:28 | Error |

I need to write a Postgres query which will give me output like:

| Start Date&Time | End Date&Time |
| --- | --- |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:12 | 13/07/2022 8:59:15 |
| 13/07/2022 8:59:24 | 13/07/2022 8:59:26 |

The scenario is - if there is any 'Error' message, I need to take the start time of 'Warning' and end time of Warning, and if there is no 'Error' message after 'Warning' ignore it e.g. after 13/07/2022 8:59:20 Warning' there is no error, so query should ignore that range.
Please help to find a query for this.

Setup table queries:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY
, message VARCHAR(10)
, datetimestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);

SET datestyle = 'DMY';
INSERT INTO test_data VALUES
  (09, 'Normal' , '13/07/2022 8:59:09')
, (10, 'Normal' , '13/07/2022 8:59:10')
, (11, 'Normal' , '13/07/2022 8:59:11')
, (12, 'Warning', '13/07/2022 8:59:12')
, (13, 'Warning', '13/07/2022 8:59:13')
, (14, 'Warning', '13/07/2022 8:59:14')
, (15, 'Warning', '13/07/2022 8:59:15')
, (16, 'Error'  , '13/07/2022 8:59:16')
, (17, 'Error'  , '13/07/2022 8:59:17')
, (18, 'Warning', '13/07/2022 8:59:18')
, (19, 'Warning', '13/07/2022 8:59:19')
, (20, 'Warning', '13/07/2022 8:59:20')
, (21, 'Normal' , '13/07/2022 8:59:21')
, (22, 'Normal' , '13/07/2022 8:59:22')
, (23, 'Normal' , '13/07/2022 8:59:23')
, (24, 'Warning', '13/07/2022 8:59:24')
, (25, 'Warning', '13/07/2022 8:59:25')
, (26, 'Warning', '13/07/2022 8:59:26')
, (27, 'Error'  , '13/07/2022 8:59:27')
, (28, 'Error'  , '13/07/2022 8:59:28')
;
```

Comment: Aside: Use unambiguous ISO format wherever possible. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69451546/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12426809/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem.

```sql
SELECT min(datetimestamp) FILTER (WHERE message = 'Warning') AS start_warning
     , max(datetimestamp) FILTER (WHERE message = 'Warning') AS end_warning
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE message = 'Warning' AND last_msg <> 'Warning')
                   OVER (ORDER BY datetimestamp) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT datetimestamp, message
           , lag(message) OVER (ORDER BY datetimestamp) AS last_msg
      FROM   test_data
      ) sub1
   WHERE  message IN ('Warning', 'Error')
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY grp
HAVING bool_or(message = 'Error' AND last_msg = 'Warning');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=39a0f2191241c294da5959a9a95a68cf)*

The query starts a new group whenever a 'Warning' is preceded by something else. And it only reports times when the 'Warning' block is followed by an 'Error'. You can have any number of different message types (except for `NULL`), these are the only conditions.

The expensive part is the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). (In particular when using different window frames.) This query makes do with a single window function and a single sort order. So it should be as fast (and simple) as it gets.

Related:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

About the aggregate `FILTER`:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Comment: thank you for reply. Along with the start and end datetime I need to fetch two more column details(Posted separately - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73176222/postgres-find-start-and-end-date-time-and-corresponding-column-value-based-on-co). Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the below script.

```
WITH cte AS
(
         SELECT   id,
                  message,
                  datetimestamp,
                  Extract( second FROM datetimestamp )::bigint - rank() over(partition BY message ORDER BY datetimestamp) AS gap
         FROM     (
                         SELECT id,
                                message,
                                datetimestamp
                         FROM   (
                                         SELECT   id,
                                                  message,
                                                  datetimestamp ,
                                                  lag(message) OVER (ORDER BY datetimestamp) ,
                                                  lead(message) OVER (ORDER BY datetimestamp) ,
                                                  lag(message,1) OVER (ORDER BY datetimestamp) IN ('Normal',
                                                                                                   'Warning') AS step1 ,
                                                  lead(message,1) OVER (ORDER BY datetimestamp) IN ('Warning',
                                                                                                    'Error') AS step2 ,
                                                  lag(message,2) OVER (ORDER BY datetimestamp) IN ('Normal',
                                                                                                   'Warning') AS step3 ,
                                                  lead(message,2) OVER (ORDER BY datetimestamp) IN ('Warning',
                                                                                                    'Error') AS step4
                                         FROM     test_data
                                         ORDER BY datetimestamp) sub1
                         WHERE  step1
                         AND    step2
                         AND    step3
                         AND    step4
                         AND    message = 'Warning' ) sub )
SELECT   gap,
         min(datetimestamp),
         max(datetimestamp)
FROM     cte
GROUP BY gap
```

[There is one sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d250b37ece54d8801758629810b0d4ae)

Comment: thank you for reply. Along with the start and end datetime I need to fetch two more column details(Posted separately - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73176222/postgres-find-start-and-end-date-time-and-corresponding-column-value-based-on-co). Is there any way to achieve this ?