# Get data from first and last row of groups based on sequence of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, gaps-and-islands

Taking it a step further than in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73150635/939860): I have a table below with sample data.

| datetimestamp | message | server | system |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:09 | Normal | Server 1 | System 1 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:10 | Normal | Server 4 | System 2 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:11 | Normal | Server 3 | System 3 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:12 | Warning | Server 35 | System 27 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:13 | Warning | Server 5 | System 5 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:14 | Warning | Server 9 | System 6 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:15 | Warning | Server 8 | System 7 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:16 | Error | Server 12 | System 8 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:17 | Error | Server 15 | System 9 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:18 | Warning | Server 29 | System 10 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:19 | Warning | Server 22 | System 11 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:20 | Warning | Server 13 | System 12 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:21 | Normal | Server 16 | System 13 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:22 | Normal | Server 19 | System 14 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:23 | Normal | Server 21 | System 15 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:24 | Warning | Server 24 | System 16 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:25 | Warning | Server 27 | System 17 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:26 | Warning | Server 25 | System 18 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:27 | Error | Server 30 | System 23 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:28 | Error | Server 31 | System 20 |

I need to write a Postgres query which will give me output like:

| Start_Datetime | End_Datetime | Server_Start | Server_End | System_Start | System_End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:12 | 2022-07-13 08:59:15 | Server 35 | Server 8 | System 27 | System 7 |
| 2022-07-13 08:59:24 | 2022-07-13 08:59:26 | Server 24 | Server 25 | System 16 | System 18 |

If there is any 'Error' message, I need to take the start time of 'Warning' and end time of 'Warning' - and corresponding `server` and `system`! If there is no 'Error' message after 'Warning' ignore it e.g. after the warning at 2022-07-13 08:59:20 there is no error, so the query should ignore that range.

Setup table queries:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY
, message varchar(10)
, datetimestamp timestamp NOT NULL
, server varchar(10)
, system varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO test_data VALUES
  (09, 'Normal' , '2022-07-13 08:59:09', 'Server 1' , 'System 1')
, (10, 'Normal' , '2022-07-13 08:59:10', 'Server 4' , 'System 2')
, (11, 'Normal' , '2022-07-13 08:59:11', 'Server 3' , 'System 3')
, (12, 'Warning', '2022-07-13 08:59:12', 'Server 35', 'System 27')
, (13, 'Warning', '2022-07-13 08:59:13', 'Server 5' , 'System 5')
, (14, 'Warning', '2022-07-13 08:59:14', 'Server 9' , 'System 6')
, (15, 'Warning', '2022-07-13 08:59:15', 'Server 8' , 'System 7')
, (16, 'Error'  , '2022-07-13 08:59:16', 'Server 12', 'System 8')
, (17, 'Error'  , '2022-07-13 08:59:17', 'Server 15', 'System 9')
, (18, 'Warning', '2022-07-13 08:59:18', 'Server 29', 'System 10')
, (19, 'Warning', '2022-07-13 08:59:19', 'Server 22', 'System 11')
, (20, 'Warning', '2022-07-13 08:59:20', 'Server 13', 'System 12')
, (21, 'Normal' , '2022-07-13 08:59:21', 'Server 16', 'System 13')
, (22, 'Normal' , '2022-07-13 08:59:22', 'Server 19', 'System 14')
, (23, 'Normal' , '2022-07-13 08:59:23', 'Server 21', 'System 15')
, (24, 'Warning', '2022-07-13 08:59:24', 'Server 24', 'System 16')
, (25, 'Warning', '2022-07-13 08:59:25', 'Server 27', 'System 17')
, (26, 'Warning', '2022-07-13 08:59:26', 'Server 25', 'System 18')
, (27, 'Error'  , '2022-07-13 08:59:27', 'Server 30', 'System 23')
, (28, 'Error'  , '2022-07-13 08:59:28', 'Server 31', 'System 20')
;
```

Comment: Is an error always rized after warning or it could be rized after normal state?

Comment: Hi @Ahmed ‘Error’ comes always after Warning but sometimes the server can go to ‘Normal’ after ‘Warning’ state. But yeah ‘Error’ comes after ‘Warning’ only.

Comment: Hi @Parfait this is almost same as my another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150635/get-start-and-end-date-time-based-on-based-on-sequence-of-rows?noredirect=1#comment129196189_73150635 . Only difference is that here I have 2 more columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
With cte As 
(
  Select D.id,D.message,D.ld,D.lg,
  Coalesce(Lag(D.id) over (order by D.datetimestamp,D.id),D.id) lastWarningId,
  Coalesce(Lag(D.id, 2) over (order by D.datetimestamp,D.id),
           Lag(D.id) over (order by D.datetimestamp,D.id)) firstWarningId
  From 
  (
     Select id, message,datetimestamp, 
            Coalesce(Lead(message) Over (Order By datetimestamp,id) , 'last') as ld,
            Coalesce(lag(message) Over (Order By datetimestamp,id) , 'first') as lg
     From test_data) D
     Where D.message<> D.ld or D.message <> D.lg
 ),
cte2 As
(
  Select id,message,ld,lg, lastWarningId, 
         Case When (Select Count(*) From test_data T Where T.id Between firstWarningId and lastWarningId and T.message='Warning')=1
         Then
              lastWarningId 
         Else 
              firstWarningId 
         End as firstwarningid2
  From cte
 )
Select T.datetimestamp as Start_DateTime, T2.datetimestamp as End_DateTime, 
       T.server as Server_Start, T2.server as Server_End,
       T.system as System_Start, T2.system as System_End
  From cte2 C
  Join test_data T On T.id = C.firstwarningid2
  Join test_data T2 On T2.id = C.lastwarningid
  Where C.message='Error' And C.lg='Warning'
```

See a demo from *[uk<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5cddb42aa1264dd232239f2516dfb867)*.

The idea of this query is to find the first and last `id` for each group of messages, which is done in `cet2`. Where:

`Lag(id) over (order by datetimestamp,id)` is the last`id` of each group.

`Lag(id, 2) over (order by datetimestamp,id)` is the first `id` of each group.

Then for each group of `message='Error'` find the first and last `id` of the nearest group of `message='Warning'`, which done by `Where C.message='Error' And C.lg='Warning'`.

To get more details about how it works, try to `select * from cet2 Where message='Error' And lg='Warning'`.

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed.. it's working as expected. Cheers.

Comment: Single-row warnings would break the query. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=393ea2a88973b828f13463d81914d5a5

Comment: @RakeshItani, Ok I'll try to fix that.

Comment: @RakeshItani, the answer is updated, kindly, check and let me know if there is any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73165402/939860) to your previous question, this does the job:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT grp, datetimestamp, message, server, system
        , bool_or(message = 'Error' AND last_msg = 'Warning') OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS report  -- qualifies for report
   FROM  (
      SELECT *
           , count(*) FILTER (WHERE message = 'Warning' AND last_msg <> 'Warning') OVER (ORDER BY datetimestamp) AS grp
      FROM  (
         SELECT datetimestamp, message, server, system
              , lag(message) OVER (ORDER BY datetimestamp) AS last_msg
         FROM   test_data
         ) sub1
      WHERE  message IN ('Warning', 'Error')  -- trim noise early
      ) sub2
   )
SELECT a.datetimestamp AS start_time, z.datetimestamp AS end_time
     , a.server AS start_server, z.server AS end_server
     , a.system AS start_system, z.system AS end_system
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (grp) *
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  report
   ORDER  BY grp, datetimestamp
   ) a
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (grp) *
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  report
   AND    message = 'Warning'  -- exclude trailing errors
   ORDER  BY grp, datetimestamp DESC
   ) z USING (grp);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=59b9e148dd6d9b289d89a2195a06240e)*

Produces your desired result exactly.

This relies on unique timestamps. If there can be duplicates, work with `id` additionally (or break ties some other way).

Move the base query from the previous answer to a CTE, and add the tag `report` to mark qualifying rows - we are going to reference it multiple times.

In the outer query, use two subqueries with `DISTINCT ON` to retrieve first and last row per group, then join ...

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Get values from first and last row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170215/get-values-from-first-and-last-row-per-group/25173081#25173081)

Comment: Thank you @Erwin.. It's working as expected. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of gaps and islands problem. First detect groups of messages and then find the lead / lag group kind. Take the combinations needed. I'm using arrays to collect data ordered by `datetimestamp` so first/last item are the items needed.

```
with mg as(
  select message, count(*) n
    , min(datetimestamp) start_time
    , max(datetimestamp) end_time
    , array_agg(server order by datetimestamp) asrv
    , array_agg(system order by datetimestamp) asys
    , lag(message, 1, 'Normal') over(order by min(datetimestamp)) prevmsg
    , lead(message,1, 'Error') over(order by min(datetimestamp)) nxtmsg
  from (
    select *, row_number() over(order by datetimestamp) - row_number() over(partition by message order by datetimestamp) grp
    from test_data
  ) t
  group by message, grp
)
select start_time, end_time
  , asrv[1] start_server, asrv[n] end_server
  , asys[1] start_system, asys[n] end_system
from mg
where mg.message ='Warning' and mg.prevmsg='Normal' and mg.nxtmsg='Error'
```

[db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=da2cde2ea1b77e9287928af51a2fb05c)

Comment: @RakeshItani, .. Edited the answer using correct sample data.